# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "x" at path "y" for model "Answer"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Another CastError question! None of the Cast error solutions I see on SO seems to solve my problem. I created schemas below to link my entities but I'm stuck on how to create/persist on the database n the docs are quite confusing after getting the basics. Is there a way of getting ObjectId from the database for the user coz I need it in `route.post()`

```js
var QuestionSchema = Schema({
    id          : ObjectId,
    title       : String,
    employees   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});

var UserSchema = Schema({
    username    : String,
    //response    : String,
    questions   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
});  

//new schema/collection I've had to create
var AnswerSchema = Schema({
    response    : {type :String, default:null},
    question    : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Question'},
    employees   : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswersSchema);
```

**api**

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res){
        User.findOne({ username: req.params. }).exec(function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);//null

            if(err) throw err;

            if(!user) {

                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate user' })
            } else if (user) {
                Question.findOne({ title:"Should we buy a coffee machine?"})
                    .exec(function (err, docs){
                    res.json(docs);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    

    //for feedback
    router.post('/', function (req, res) {
        User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).exec(function(err, user) {
            if(err) throw err;

            if(!user) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate user' })
            } else if (user){
                Answer.findOneAndUpdate({
                            question: req.body.question_id,
                            employee: req.body.user_id //CastError points to here
                        },
                        req.body, 
                        {
                            upsert: true  
                        })
                .exec(function(err, answer) {
                    console.log(err);//Cast error shows up here
                    console.log(answer);//prints undefined
                });
                console.log('entry saved to answer >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's hard to tell where your problems are as you have many errors. Off the bat, in your GET route, what is `{ username: req.params. }`? I don't even think that is valid JS. In your POST route, where did you get `employee`? Your schema has an array field called `employees` so you would have to do `employees: { $in: [req.body.user_id] }`.

Comment: With regards to querying on the `employees` field, you can actually just do `employees: req.body.user_id`

Comment: Also, we need to know more about what the request looks like in order to be able to answer the question. What does `req.body.user_id` look like exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I figured out all my mistakes. I was unnecessarily using ObjectId's. It's my first project using mongodb. Everything works now.

Comment: That's great, well done!